# How do you extract multiple elements by their name in matrix or list in R?

Tags: r

I have created a matrix in which I have many elements in 3 columns called:
example

```
SYMBOL  NAME     FUNCTION
c       cat      pet
d       dog      first aid
b       bird     song
m       monkey   forest
```

etc

I have a an object done like this : c("c","d").
My objective is to look for the presence of my multiples objects: "c" and "d" and to obatin the entire row, something like:
"c" "cat" "pet"
"d" "dog" "fist aid".
I have tried with functions "which" to know the entire row of a single element but I am not able to look for various elements because if I do
which (matrix == "c")
answer: [1] 1
and then
matrix[1, ]
but this is sooo long and I cannot look for multiple elements.
Any help please?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

There’s no need for `which`. Conversely, since you want to return *multiple* rows based on multiple IDs, you need to use the `%in%` operator instead of equality comparison via `==`.

The following code will return the matching rows from a matrix named `mat`:

```
mat[mat[, "SYMBOL"] %in% c("c", "d"), ]
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I have already tried this but R says to me: Erreur dans combinedmatrix_2$SYMBOL : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: @martamarta Ah, your question did mention that your data is in a matrix, but I just assumed it was a data.frame. For matrices, the code needs to be slightly changed; see update.